# determining where column collations don't match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the below collation conflict error when I try to join two fairly large tables via a UNION ALL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLEA] 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [TABLEB]

Msg 457, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" in UNION ALL operator.
```

I would like to identify which columns exactly are mismatched but am unfamiliar with querying sys.columns or information_schema.

Comment: If you highlight a table in SSMS and press ALT-F1, it will display the table schema, including collation.  Quick and easy -- you can do this for both tables, drop them side-by-side in excel, and add a <> formula to compare the Collation values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do (assuming that the columns on both tables have the same names):

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'TABLEA') A
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM sys.columns
            WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'TABLEB') B
    ON A.name = B.name
WHERE A.collation_name <> B.collation_name
```

Comment: that is assuming a lot.

Comment: Yes my column names match, and yes I'm using 2008 R2.  This is short simple and exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `MyTable1` and `MyTable2` with your tables names

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) as TableName
       ,c.name AS ColumnName
       ,c.collation_name as CollationName
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    JOIN sys.tables AS t
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name IN ( 'MyTableA', 'MyTableB' )
    AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
```

In case column names are exactly the same than you can do this

```
WITH    TableA
          AS (
               SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS TableName
                   ,c.name AS ColumnName
                   ,c.collation_name AS CollationName
                FROM sys.columns AS c
                JOIN sys.tables AS t
                    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                WHERE t.name IN ( 'TableA' )
                    AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
             ),
        TableB
          AS (
               SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS TableName
                   ,c.name AS ColumnName
                   ,c.collation_name AS CollationName
                FROM sys.columns AS c
                JOIN sys.tables AS t
                    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                WHERE t.name IN ( 'TableB' )
                    AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
             )
    SELECT a.TableName
           ,a.ColumnName
           ,a.CollationName
           ,b.TableName
           ,b.ColumnName
           ,b.CollationName
        FROM tableA AS a
        JOIN TableB AS b
            ON a.ColumnName = b.ColumnName
               AND a.CollationName <> b.CollationName
```

Answer (score 1):

OK everyone's using `sys.columns`... I'll use `information_schema` just in case he's on SQL 2000 ;)

If column names are the same (and in same order):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEA') A,
     (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEB') B
WHERE A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
AND ISNULL(A.COLLATION_NAME,'') <> ISNULL(B.COLLATION_NAME,'')
```

Or, to compare by column order (ordinal):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableA') A
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableB') B
   ON A.ORDINAL_POSITION = B.ORDINAL_POSITION
WHERE ISNULL(A.COLLATION_NAME,'') <> ISNULL(B.COLLATION_NAME,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in that direction.

```
 WITH CTE as 
(   SELECT tbl.NAME AS Table_name
        , col.NAME AS [Column_name]
        , col.collation_name
        , col.column_id
    FROM sys.columns col
    INNER JOIN sys.tables tbl
        ON col.object_id = tbl.object_id  
    WHERE Col.collation_name in ('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
    ,'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS')    
 )
 SELECT * FROM CTE A
 inner join CTE b
 on A.column_id=B.column_id
 WHERE A.Table_name='PSS601'
 and B.Table_name='PSS604'
 and A.collation_name <> B.collation_name
```

Then to change the collation use the COLLATE keyword.

```
Column_name COLLATE Collation_name
```